# php: как отключить вывод предупреждений в подключаемом файле

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Есть файл, который я подключаю конструкцией include_once. Подключение этого файла выдает предупреждение Warning. К сожалению, я не могу эту ошибку устранить - файл генерируется автоматически другой программой, но содержит данные необходимые для работы другого скрипта.

Я пытался поставить символ @ перед подключением, это не помогло. 
Я пытался чистить буфер вывода после подключения скрипта (ob_clean) - нет, тоже не помогло. 
Я пробовал разные эксперименты с подавлением ошибок, типа error_reporting(0) - не помогло.

То есть, убрать предупреждение скрипта для меня какая-то сейчас неустранимая проблема. Дело усугубляется тем, что люди, которые отвечают за формирования скрипта тоже не могут это предупреждение убрать, а оно вылезает в пользовательском интерфейсе.

Само предупреждение выглядит так: Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/php_sess/sess_5440871b1140140ebаап4fa1c0417a, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Права выставили на 777 на всю папку, но безрезультатно.

Плюс, есть еще странность. Это предупреждение всегда в конце вывода. То есть, я подключаю этот файл командой include, затем делаю echo 123;

Вывод скрипта: 
123 
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/php_sess/sess_5440871b1140140ebаап4fa1c0417a, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

То есть, срабатывают какие-то обработчики при завершении? Куда копать?

Спасибо!

Comment: место на диске есть? квоты, мб какие или еще чего настроено?

Comment: `ob_clean` и `@` тут не к месту. Вывод сообщения происходит не "всегда в конце", а именно тогда, когда возникает ошибка. `error_reporting()` если вы отключаете, а оно все равно показывается, значит где то далее репортинг включается обратно. Что у вас дальше в файле? если создать пустой скрипт и стартануть сессию, будут ошибки?

Comment: А вот в том-то и дело, что сперва идет вывод скрипта, а потом уже текст предупреждения.  То есть, 
1 Я делаю инклюд
2 Вывожу какие-то строки
3 В конце вывода идет это предупреждения.

Если инклюд не делаю, то и предупреждений нет. Сборщик мусора чудит?